# ubuntu20.4 does not suspend or restart after restarting or suspending system

Tags: suspend, restart, amd-processor

I just installed ubuntu 20.4 and after a while, when I restart or suspend the system, the system raises only one black screen and does nothing and then the CPU fan starts spinning at high speed.
where is the problem from?
hardware: asus laptop 3GHz AMD FX-9830p cpu 4 core